# How do I get sessionid in Flutter for making a visualizer?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a visualizer using flutter and [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_visualizers/example) dependency. But I'm unable to fetch the sessionId. How do I proceed?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "unable to fetch" the sessionId? Does it throw an exception? If so, what does it say?

Comment: I don't know how to fetch the sessionId in flutter.And I wasn't able to find the same on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this : [github.com/iamSahdeep/FlutterVisualizers](https://github.com/iamSahdeep/FlutterVisualizers/tree/master/example)
It gives a full example of the lib

Comment: I did look there, but it's still not working.!!! Is there any other audio visualizer for flutter?